# In Microsoft SQL Server, will 2 non clustered indices improve performance when there is already a non clustered composite index?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a table called Files that contains these columns

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[RowVersion] [timestamp] NULL,
[CreatedAt] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
[UpdatedAt] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
[FileName] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
[FileContent] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[MessengerId] [int] NOT NULL,
[FileTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Ref] [int] NOT NULL,
```

The table has a clustered index on the primary key Id.

Also there is a non clustered composite index on MessengerId and FileName

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Files_CourierId_FileName] ON [dbo].[Files]
(
    [MessengerId] ASC,
    [FileName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This query is slow

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Files WHERE MessengerId = 1 AND Filename = 'myfilename.xml'
```

I'm battling to test because the timeouts happen on a production server. On my developper laptop I have no issues.

**Will adding 2 new indices on MessengerId and Filename improve performance?**

The 2 new indices look like so

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index_on_FileName] ON [dbo].[Files]
(
    [FileName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index_on_MessengerId] ON [dbo].[Files]
(
    [MessengerId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: The current index is a covering index and can be used to satisfy your query without having to lookup rows in the table. Neither of the proposed indices are covering, so the query would have to resort to table seeks/scans to find the remaining data. Your issue could be stale statistics or parameter sniffing. Also have a read through [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: Aside from query plan issues, the issue could also be general server load or applications holding row locks (for the latter, you can look into things like snapshot isolation). The only thing you can be pretty sure is not the issue is the usefulness of the index. If you want to know if an (existing or new) index helps, always look at the query plan before and after; in this case that should have told (even in a test environment) that the new indexes would not be used by your query in preference to the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

This query

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Files WHERE MessengerId = 1 AND Filename = 'myfilename.xml'
```

requires a index equality-lookup on `MessengerId` and `Filename` and no other columns, so you current index will suffice.

You could equally switch the column order for the same result (you may find it a *tiny* bit faster in the event there is no match)

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Files_CourierId_FileName] ON [dbo].[Files]
(
    [FileName] ASC,
    [MessengerId] ASC
)
```

However the other two new indexes you propose do not cover the query, so the server most likely not even bother using them, especially if your existing query is still in place. Certainly they will be slower if used, as they will require key lookups to the clustered index.

---

Your actual timeout issue is more likely associated with locking because of other queries doing updates. I suggest you use a query to find any possible blockers, for example [this one](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/07/07/sql-server-identifying-blocking-chain-using-sql-scripts/).